# Unexpected behavior of RTL alert box in chrome

Tags: javascript

I try to execute this alert box in chrome with a Arabic sentence:

the code is this:

```
alert('سلام علیکم.');
```

When I execute it inside my code in a `.js` file, unexpectedly the text gets distorted:

[image]

And when I try to execute it right in the chrome's console it shows the correct sentence:

[image]

Why and how to fix this?

Comment: Look at the HTTP transactions (via the developer "Network" tool) to check what the character encodings are for your main page and your JavaScript sources. If they're not UTF-8 then that might be messing up the string.

Comment: Could you please expalin it a bit... How can I check what the character encodings are.. ?

Comment: Please try like this : alert("\u202bسلام علیکم.");

Comment: You can also try https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/

Comment: Guys... If I run my code inside a server it works but when I try to run the code from my laptop the problem appears! Why?

Comment: any console error ? Check network for any error.

Comment: by the way which encoding you are using ?